# ¿Cómo evitar filas repetidas al ingresar datos en un DataGridView?

Tags: c#, puertos, timer, datagrid

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación que mediante una antena UHF escanea constantemente en busca de RFID's. Si detecta una nueva RFID la ingresa al `DataGridView`, si esa RFID ya había sido ingresada entonces pinta la fila de verde y si hay una en el `DataGridView` que no haya sido detectada de nuevo entonces la pinta de blanco.
Sí funciona, el problema es que entre menor sea el lapso de tiempo entre cada escaneo y más sean las RFID's empieza a repetirlas. 
Según yo el problema yace en que varios hilos detectan e ingresan la misma RFID simultáneamente, le puse un lock en el timer para evitar eso, pero lo único que logré fue que funcionara con un mínimo de 200 milisegundos entre cada escaneo.

¿Hay algún modo de mejorarlo? 
La idea es poder detectar el mayor número de tarjetas en el menor tiempo posible.

```
void tmrRepeatedScan_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            lock (thisLock)
            {
                var detectedTags = serialPort.Scan(true, false, true, false);

                foreach (var tag in detectedTags)
                {
                    bool tagFound = false;
                    string TID = Regex.Replace(Conversions.ByteToHexadecimal(tag.GetTagId()), "(.{2})(?!$)", "$0-");
                    string EPC = Regex.Replace(Conversions.ByteToHexadecimal(tag.GetEpc()), "(.{2})(?!$)", "$0-");

                    if (!tagsReaded.Contains(TID))
                    {
                        tagsReaded.Add(TID);
                    }

                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvTags.Rows)
                    {
                        if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Equals(TID))
                        {
                            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                            tagFound = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (!tagFound)
                    {
                        dgvTags.BeginInvoke(new InvokeDelegate(() => AddRow(TID, EPC)));
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvTags.Rows)
            {
                if (!tagsReaded.Contains(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()))
                {
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvTags.Rows)
            {
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yo utilizaria un unico hilo para leer cada x milisegundos, pero no guardaria esa informacion en el datagrid directamente, sino que lo guardaria en una Lista. Una vez terminada la lectura comprobaria la lista si estan duplicados, etc, y haria lo que toque segun tus necesidades, y ya despues en funcion de lo que haya quedado en la lista pintaria el datagrid, y todo esto en un while infinito

Comment: Lo otro. Si no lo encuentras, Agréga el row y pintalo de color blanco, en el metodo AddRow. No vuelvas a iterar. No tiene sentido

Comment: Utilizas la lista solo para comprobar que existe el TIC?. Crea un objeto que guarde el TIC y si es nuevo.  Luego le pasas la lista a la grilla y dibujas una sola vez.

Comment: Es que la idea es que se muestre en tiempo real la detección de las RFID's. Si las guardara en una lista y al final las agregara en el datagrid, ya no sería en tiempo real. Lo de pintarlos no es estrictamente necesario, sólo lo hago para que se vea cuando una RFID sale o permanece en el rango de la antena. Lo de los múltiples hilos no sé cómo evitarlo, según yo esos lo tiene el timer por defecto, puse el Timer de System.Timers porque con ese podía hacer otras cosas en la ventana mientras la antena escaneaba.